# Add new data to database by adding 1 to the last data

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of data in the database. I need to insert new data automatically after the status change to "In use" from "New" in the database by adding 1 to "End Range" to get the next "Start Range". For the end range, it will add the new start range with "FFFF". The range is in hexadecimal format.

For example, the previous start and end range is 10120000, 1012FFFF. For the next new range that need to be inserted, it will take the 1012FFFF and plus it with 1. so the start range for the next data should be 10130000. While for the end range, it will add the 10130000 with FFFF and the result is 1013FFFF.

The status for the next range that inserted will be assigned as 'New'.

How can i do this for the new range with same format with previous range? Should i create trigger?

Example of data in db

[image: 1]

Comment: You'll need to use transactions so that you can read the "last" row and lock the table (locking in **very** important) and then write said next row to the table.

Comment: can i know how can i do that? cause i have no idea about the transactions and locking table. is there any link that can i refer to? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *real* problem here is that when you get the value of the "latest" row there *could* be another `INSERT` that is running at the same time; in such a scenario you *could* end up with a race condition, meaning that both `INSERT` statement use the same value for their start number,

As a result you need to lock the table when you read it, so that you can then "add 1" to it. Let's start off with some sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (StartRange binary(4),
                            EndRange binary(4),
                            Status varchar(10));
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (StartRange,
                           EndRange,
                           Status)
VALUES(0x10100000,0x1010FFFF,'In Use'),
      (0x10110000,0x1011FFFF,'In Use'),
      (0x10120000,0x1012FFFF,'In Use');
```

We can then use a lock, update the table. The gap you want `0xFFFF`, in integer terms is `65535` so we can also add that to the end value:

```sql
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION NewRow;

    DECLARE @End binary(4);

    SELECT TOP (1)
           @End = EndRange
    FROM dbo.YourTable WITH (UPDLOCK,TABLOCK)
    ORDER BY EndRange DESC;

    INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (StartRange,
                               EndRange,
                               Status)
    VALUES(@End + 1, @End + 65535 + 1, 'In Use');

    COMMIT TRANSACTION NewRow;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION NewRow;
    THROW;

END CATCH;
```

Answer (score 0):

"Sequence" is best solution

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkMKT.png)

by this script you can create Sequence in sql server

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[Seq1] AS [bigint]
 START WITH 1010
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE -9223372036854775808
 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
 CACHE 
GO
```

---

by this code you can get new value

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR seq1;
```

---

and insert time

```
INSERT INTO TableName (StartRange)
VALUES(SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR seq1);
```

---

at the end Full sample

```
DECLARE @StartRange varchar(4);
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT @StartRange = (NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].seq1)', N'@StartRange int output', @StartRange = @StartRange output;

INSERT INTO TableName (StartRange, EndRange, Status)
SELECT  @StartRange  + '0000'   AS  StartRange
        ,@StartRange + 'FFFF'   AS  EndRange
        ,'In Use'               AS  Status
```

---